# Magento Connect - DEBUG (7): <config/>

Tags: magento

In Magento Connect when I Check For Updates the page refreshes but nothing gets highlighted as needing an update (even though we aren't using the latest version of Magento).

When I check the system.log I get these entries at the same time I tried checking for the updates:

```
DEBUG (7): <config/>
```

Any ideas what this vague error message relates to?

Answer (score 2):

Someone where in one of the PHP files that runs during your page request, someone has added something like the following.

```
Mage::log($somevar->asXml());
Mage::log($somevar);
Mage::log('<confnig/>');
```

This is most likely some temporary debugging code left over from a previous developer's attempts to debug the site.

Regarding why nothing shows up as needing updates -- that's because Magento Connect in Magento 1 is broken.  If you haven't been using it to keep things up to date since the start of your system, and if you haven't monitored the permissions and health of its config/state files, Magento Connect can easily lose track of your system's state.  Most Magento professionals don't trust it, and perform upgrades of the core system and extensions manually.

Comment: Thanks.  I will have a look for the debug code.  We started in Magento 1.4 and have upgrade all the way through to 1.9.0.1 so Connect worked well for us until recently.  Not sure what has caused it to stop.

Comment: I downloaded a copy of our site and did a search for <config/> and didn't get any results relating to Mage::log.  I only got lines of code like $unsortedConfig->loadString('<config/>');

Answer (score 0):

It is

```
$mergeToObject->loadString('<config/>');
```

In the "app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Config.php"

```
"public function loadModulesConfiguration"
```

It is annoying, but nothing to do. 
Varien can't recognize  as valid XML.